# Redux Form Variables

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
export const fields = [ 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'sex', 'favoriteColor', 'employed', 'notes' ]

class SimpleForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      fields: { firstName, lastName, email, sex, favoriteColor, employed, notes },
      handleSubmit,
      resetForm,
      submitting
      } = this.props
    return (<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" {...firstName}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" {...lastName}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
```

This is a `Simple Form` example from `redux-form` package. I am puzzled where the variable `firstName` come from. Is there something I'm missing from the ES6 syntax?

Comment: It came from `this.props.fields.firstName` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ES6 concept you might be missing is called "destructuring object assignment":

This assignment:

```
const {
  fields: { firstName, lastName, email, sex, favoriteColor, employed, notes },
  handleSubmit,
  resetForm,
  submitting
  } = this.props
```

means that `this.props` has the shape

```
{ fields: { firstName: "...", 
            lastName: "...", 
            email: "...", 
            sex: "...", 
            favoriteColor: "...", 
            employed: "...", 
            notes: "..."
          },
  handleSubmit: "...",
  resetForm: "...",
  submitting: "..."
}
```

where "..." stands for any datatype (including objects and arrays), not just Strings. Also, the object may contain more information than that.

Destructuring assignment allows to deeply reach into the object structure and assign names to elements of that object. In our case, each of the "..." values I sketched above is directly assigned to a variable. These variables can subsequently be used on their own. That's where `firstName` comes from.

The code then applies another new ES6 thing called the "object spread operator": Passing `{...firstName}` allows to split up the `firstName` object and to pass each of its properties to the React component individually.
Say, `firstName` looks like this:

```
{ a: "...", b: "...", c: "..." }
```

then

```
<MyComponent {...firstName} />
```

is equivalent to

```
<MyComponent a={firstName.a} b={firstName.b} c={firstName.c} />
```

Comment: I get that `fields.firstName` is mapped to `this.props.fields.firstName` from the initial `const` assignment. But how is `...firstName` reaching `fields.firstName`?

Comment: I have updated my answer - does it answer your question?

Comment: It's not that `fields.firstName` is mapped to `this.props.fields.firstName`, but actually `firstName` is already mapped to `this.props.fields.firstName` - it is deeply destructuring the object.

Comment: Ah, I see. So `fields` is not mapped to anything in this case?

Comment: No, in the code above, there is no variable called `fields`. Instead, the destructuring grants direct access to the properties inside the object with the key `fields`.

Answer (score 1):

you should export reduxForm and give an object argument which should  contain name of the form and fields of your form, then you can use { ...firstName} in your form. you should add this code to the bottom of your class

```
    export default SimpleForm({
       form: 'nameOfYourForm',
       fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
    }, null, actions)(SimpleForm);
```